# auto click button when javascript function is called NOT on page load or button click

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I want to auto click a button when a javascript function is called.  With the button clicked, a flask route is called.  All I have been able to find is for when the page loads.  Here is some code

```
<script>
  function justClickin(){
     $("#autoclick").get(0).click();
     // $("#autoclick").trigger('click');  // This doesnt work either
  }
</script>
```

---

```
{% if True %}
   <script>
      justClickin();
   </script>
{% endif %}
```

---

```
<a id="autoclick" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">login </a>
```

So when the condition is true, the justClickin JS function is run.  This should auto click the anchor tag and run the flask route.  Problem is that the anchor tag is not clicked.

Thanks

**Edit ------------------------------------------**

So in the end, I did this

```
{% if True %}
   <script>
      $("document").ready(function(){
         $("#autoclick").get(0).click();
      });
   </script>
{% endif %}

<a id='autoclick' style="display:none;"  href="{{ url_for('login') }}">login </a>
```

Comment: Does the element with the id autoclick exist before or after the script that calls that method?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adv8chj0/1/  works fine

Comment: Sigh - I knew it was going to be something simple.  @Taplar - Put this in the answer section and I will give it the green check.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your logic is being ran as soon as it is reached by the parser, the elements that you are trying to manipulate must already exist for you to use them.  So if the element appears on the page after the function call, it will not exist in the DOM yet for you to find and click it logically.  Your script will need to be after the element in the DOM.  Otherwise, you could put your logic in a document ready and then it would not execute until the entire page is parsed into the DOM.